# show progress icon while loading page in ViewPager

Tags: android

I am using AsyncTask in my application to load data from Internet. Here is onPostExecute method of my class that extends Async class.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Article result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    TextView txtTitle= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtTitle.setText(result.getTitle());

    TextView txtMain= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main);
    txtMain.setText(result.getContent());
}
```

This is the overridden method from PageAdapter that instantiate pages. customlayout is the layout that shows article.

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View page= inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout , null);

    Worker aw = new Worker(page, container.getContext());
    aw.execute(links.get(position));

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(page,0);
    return page;
}
```

Here is layout of a page that is inflated in each page.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

What I am trying to achieve is show a progress information until data loads. I should be able to swipe through page even while loading.
I would be grateful if anyone would help.

Also how can I control number of pages that are being loaded in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a spinning progress bar, you can try this:

xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer">
   <ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

activity:

```
private View progressContainer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(...) {
    progressContainer = v.findeViewById(R.id.progressContainer);
    progressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

So whenever you need to display the Progress just set the View to visible.

If you want to be able to still interact with your activity, you can just modify the clickability of the parent FrameLayout:

```
android:clickable="true" (or "false")
```

Set it to false if you want to interact, and true to block!

Comment: Thanks! but I didn't get what you wanted to say about clickable

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use fragments as your viewPager items, and implement the loading pattern inside the fragment i.e - https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Regarding number of pages being loaded see - [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: Second answer are very helpful.. thank you... There is one problem in my application, main page was loading slower than pages that are retained. Can you suggest a solution? Regarding first question, I would have to learn using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong. You are creating something like youtube video, fetching the frame on background and keep update it. In your case is book, fetching pages on background and keep update on it.

First, What you needs is ***fragment*** as you cannot destroy your **AsyncTask** that running on your activity.

Second, AsyncTask **publishProgress** and **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)** method, it help you to report background condition. You can take a look at the usage example provided by android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html